# Hibernate search (!) dynamic queries with DSL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have to build hibernate search queries in a dynamic way because the user is able to click and type his search in a relativly free way in the application.

The index can be defined in a static way by annotations. No problem here.

But to build the search query I have to parse a JSON-string which is the result from the search editor the user uses.

So I will learn at runtime how my query has to look.

Is there a way to use hibernate QueryBuilder to build an unknown combination of should and must keyword searches? Since I have to dig through the JSON, which describes the user build search I have to somehow build the hibernate search query in a loop. Is there a way to append to a query like in HQL?

I could do that using Lucene API. But I would prefere QueryBuilder if possible.

Thanks!

**Update**:
Since I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted with DSL I used Lucene API wich turned out to work very well.

Comment: Native Lucene queries work for sure, but conceptually you should be able to do the same with the query DSL. Native Lucene queries or Hibernate Search DSL, either way you need to hand-roll some code which translates from your JSON representation of the query to the corresponding query Hibernate Search can process. Unless you describe why the DSL did not work for you, it is hard to say where your problems lies and how you could have solved it via the DSL

Comment: Hi Thx for your question and sorry for the long time I took.
What I doo is about:
`ArrayNode node ObjectMapper.readTree(JSON);
BooleanQuery query;
for (JsonNode node : node) {
 Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = null;
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> i = node.fields();
        if (i.hasNext()) {
        //analyze entry
         query.add(new NumericRangeQuery ... new WildcardQuery...)
        }
}
hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, myClass.class);
List<MyDomainClass> queryResults = hibQuery.list();`
The User can define JSON contents at runtime.

Comment: What I missed with DSL was query.add because my query WildCard, NumericRange etc depends on the contents of the JSON.

Comment: It is even more complicated because user can also define parenthesis for his custom query  which I have to incoorporte into my query...